# Tread 9: EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, multithreading

I get this message "Tread 9: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x70000010) in this method (but this bug is being created only when in another thread file is being downloaded ):

```
- (NSMutableDictionary *) getDictionaryAllStatin:(sqlite3*)database
{

    if (self._streetsArrey == nil || self._streetsArrey.count <= 0) {
        [self getArrayAllStatin:database];
    }

    /*--------------------------------------------------------------*/
    NSMutableDictionary *result1 = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    for (StreetData *street in _streetsArrey) {
        NSString * name = [self deleteContractionWithText:street._name];
        NSArray * arr = [name componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
        NSMutableArray *arrm = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:arr];
        arr = nil;
        [arrm addObject:name];

            for (NSString *txt in arrm) {
                int lengthText = txt.length;
                for (int i = 2 ; i <= lengthText; i++) {
                    NSString * key = [txt substringToIndex:i];
                    key = [key lowercaseString];
                    NSMutableDictionary *isSet = [result1 objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[key hash]]];
                    if (isSet == nil) {
                        isSet = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
                    }
                    [isSet setObject:street forKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:street._streetId]];
                    [result1 setObject:isSet forKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[key hash]]];
                    isSet = nil;
                    key = nil;
                }
            }

    }

    NSMutableDictionary *result = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    for (id key in result1) {
        NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [result1 objectForKey:key];
        NSArray *arr = [dictionary allValues];
        [result setObject:arr forKey:key];
        arr = nil;
        [dictionary removeAllObjects];
        dictionary = nil;

    }
    [result1 removeAllObjects];
    result1 = nil;
    /*--------------------------------------------------------------*/
    if (result.count > 0) {
        _streetsDictionary = result;
        result = nil;
        return _streetsDictionary;
    }else {
        _streetsDictionary = nil;
        return nil;
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

**Why do I get this message?**

**How can I fix it?**

Comment: you can debug your code using Breakpoints.

Comment: )) i did it. But when i debug my code i did't get this message

Comment: check out did u get all values in your dictionary

Comment: i think you have to pass String for key like
NSDictionary *dicTemp = [result objectForKey:@"STRING-VALUE"];

Comment: Well `NSNumber` conforms to `NSCopying` so that part is OK but making a number out of the hash of the string and using it for the key is not something I've seen before. But not sure if it's part of the problem.

Comment: I have fixed this problem, but now I get some message: 

`malloc: *** error for object 0x81a9e00: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
`

       

**what does it mean?
**what can I do to fix this problem?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most likely cause for the crash is trying to access an object that has already been deallocated.

Since it seems that the failure arises on the line:

```
  NSMutableDictionary *isSet = [result1 objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[key hash]]];
```

I would suggest splitting the statement down to its component to try and track down which object could actually be the culprit:

```
 NSInteger h = [key hash];
 NSNumber n = [NSNumber numberWithInt:h];
 ...
```

> but this bug is being created only when in another thread file is being downloaded

Also, check if the downloading code and the crashing code have anything in common. The former might be causing the deallocation of an object used in the second.

Hope it helps.